# Python OCR - How to get the correct image graph(image contains UTC timestamp) that same with current UTC timestamp while script executed

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

kindly help for my issues.
Disclaimer:

1. I'm not allowed to install anything on the machine that run my script, i'm using portable python 3.10.2 x64
2. Tesseract OCR i used also portable, tesseract-ocr 3.02 win32 portable.

I want to get the correct image graph, correct image means, image graph that have utc timestamp(position on right side of the graph) match with current utc time.
But, the problem are image link somehow changed, imagexxxx.192.168.12(2).45.chart1.png?epoch_timestamp or imagexxxx.192.168.12(4).45.chart1.png?epoch_timestamp.

Changes are between 192.168.12(2).45.chart1.png or 192.168.12(4).45.chart1.png

My script are Selenium python with tesseract OCR.
Because there's ip changed on image link, with selenium, i screenshot both link and save as png image.

```
driver.save_screenshot("GX_122.png")
driver.save_screenshot("GX_124.png")
```

Crop the image, to get the utc timestamp(Hour:Minute) that located on right side graph.
`cropped = image.crop((868,185,962,201))`

Resize the cropped image, to make it bigger size, save both.
`img = img.resize((basewidth,hsize))`
save as GX_crop122.png and GX_crop124.png

And Now the OCR step with compare utc
I made a lot of if because ocr read number 0 as 9, this are my workaround for ocr issue.

```
pytesseract_path = r"C:\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe"
gx122_path = r"C:\GX_crop122.png"
ocr1 = Image.open(gx122_path)
pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = pytesseract_path
gx122_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(ocr1)
oprint(gx122_text)
utc1 = gx122_text[:2] #Take only Hours (2 digit)
gx122_time1 = utc1[:1] #first digit
gx122_time2 = utc1[-1:] #second digit
if gx122_time1 == "9": gx122_time1 = 0
gx122_graph = f'{gx122_time1}{gx122_time2}'
if gx122_graph == "29": gxtotal192_graph = 20
if (gx122_graph == "09" and now_utc == "00"): gx122_graph = 00
if (gx122_graph == "19" and now_utc == "10"): gx122_graph = 10
if (gx122_graph == "19" and now_utc == "19"): gx122_graph = 19
oprint(f'{gx122_graph}')

gx122_Before = r"C:\Python\GX_122.png"
gx122_After = r"C:\Python\GX_utc.png"
try:
    if gx122_graph == now_utc: os.rename(gx122_Before, gx122_After)
except WindowsError:
    os.remove(gx122_After)
    os.rename(gx122_Before, gx122_After)
```

Script are running ok, no error, sometimes it's working, sometimes error on the image.
Sometimes there's no file GX_utc.png, i'm not sure why.
I want if the cropped image time same with current utc time, then i will use the image(before cropped by OCR = GX_122.png) by renaming the image to GX_utc.png, then sent the email report.

Did i do wrong on the IF? Or on the try catch?
I'm open if there's another way to get the result that i wanted :)

Thanks

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).